NumPy: find (continguous) occurrences of submatrix
I have a matrix Y and a matrix A with dimensions less than those of Y. What is a fast way in numpy to find where A occurs as a contiguous submatrix of Y (say, the index to the top-left corner)?
For example, if I have
A = np.array([[1, 0],
              [0, 1]])
Y = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 1],
              [1, 0, 0]])

Then I would like the result to be
[[0, 1]]

since A occurs as the submatrix starting at the first row and second column.
I know this would be easy to implement with loops, but I would like something that runs faster.

An naive solution (which will likely be the first answer proposed soon) is to search for every location of the matrix which runs in O(n² m²) where n is A.shape[0] and m is Y.shape[0] (assume matrices are square for sake of simplicity). The question is then : how big are the matrices in practice? Indeed, this solution can be insanely slow for big matrices (eg. hours for matrices n and m >2000). Also what is the exact data-type in pratice?

@JérômeRichard In practice the larger matrix has size around 100x100, while the smaller matrix is 2x2. Data type is int. I realized after posting this that the matrices I am dealing with have extra structure which makes the problem easier, but I thought I would leave the question up out of curiosity.

In Y those values are not contiguous. The usual 'find' is to expand dimensions as needed, do a X==Y and then 'all/any' to reduce dimensions.  But the intermediate array(s) will be big, even with the help of sliding windows.

@hpaulj Do you just have a different meaning of "contiguous" in mind, or what do you mean?

@nocomment, I was thinking about the underlying (raveled) data. (or in the c/f sense).  But for searching purposes it might not matter.

Then a naive solution is certainly fine (eg. the answer Onyambu). Searching for the top-left value might first even be faster for a 2x2 matrix, especially if the integers is bigger than [0;1].

You can use sliding window. Although this will be slow:
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

np.argwhere((swv(Y, A.shape) == A).all((2,3)))

array([[0, 1]], dtype=int64)


np.array(np.where(...)).T -> np.argwhere(...)

Depending on the values, signal.correlate might work. It might be fast, since it can use FFT.
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

A = np.array([[1, 0],
              [0, 1]])
Y = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 1],
              [1, 0, 0]])

out = signal.correlate(Y, A, mode='valid', method='fft')
# array([[0, 2],
#        [0, 0]])
indices = np.where(out == (A * A).sum())  # perfect agreement
# (array([0]), array([1]))

If not, it would at least give you some candidate locations, which you could check directly. Whether that would be effective depends on the values, specifically how common it is for the matrices to be different but happen to have the same Frobenius inner product (inner product when treated as vectors) as the square of A's Frobenius norm.
You can also manipulate the values to try to avoid this possibility. In the example above, for instance, you could have replaced zeros with -1 so that only a perfect match would give a correlation of 4.
You could also consider template matching functions in a computer vision library (e.g. https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html).

Test with random arrays of the appropriate size
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

rng = np.random.default_rng(32489234932)

max = 100
n = 100
Y = rng.integers(max, size=(n, n))

i = rng.integers(n - 2)
j = rng.integers(n - 2)
A = Y[i:i+2, j:j+2]

def correlate(Y, A):
    out = signal.correlate(Y, A, mode='valid', method='fft')
    return np.where(out == (A * A).sum())

def sliding_window(Y, A):
    return np.array(np.where((swv(Y, A.shape) == A).all((2,3)))).T


%timeit correlate(Y, A)
# 336 µs ± 7.47 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit sliding_window(Y, A)
# 734 µs ± 87.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In this case, both find the correct i, j, but again, it's possible that correlate will return false matches.

Changed to use np.argwhere

This will fail, in cases where there is no match. or might even return false matches. Suppose Y = np.array([[1, 1, 1],[1, 0, 1],[1, 1, 1]]), there should be no matches. Or even if Y = np.array([[1, 1, 0],[1, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1]])

Yes. I addressed that a few times in the response, e.g. the first sentence.

Note that an FFT if completely overkill for integer values. In fact, it might also be incorrect in some cases due to the loss of information of the FFT, especially if some integers are big (i.e. impulse noise).

Nonetheless, it appears to be faster than sliding window in some cases, and that is what the OP requested. Is it wrong to think outside the sliding box? The answer is up front about the fact that it might not work. Let the user decide whether it happens to be useful to them them. If not, that's fine. It still might be useful to someone else.
